# Win32Com python create global instance and use it in flask function

Tags: python, flask, win32com, pythoncom

I am currently trying to run the following piece of code but I keep getting the error that

> > pywintypes.com_error: (-2147417842, 'The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.', None, None)

Do i need to execute the flask function through a separate thread. Is there no other way of just creating a global excel instance and using it to open and modify separate workbooks?

Any help regarding the same would be highly appreciated.

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import json   
import pythoncom
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import Dispatch

xl = None
xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/check", methods=['POST'])
def check():

    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.get_json()
        fname = data['fname']
        phName = data['PH_Name']
        liName = data['LI_NAME']
        ppm = data['PPM']
        policyTerm = data['Policy_Term']
        sumAssured = data['Sum_Assured']


        wb = None

        if xl : 
            wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(fname) 


            inp_sheet = wb.Sheets["Inputs"]

            #read data from sheet
            data = inp_sheet.Range('D8').Value


            wb.Close(False)
            xl.Quit()
            return (data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(threaded=True, port=5001, debug=True)
```

Comment: Cant you use any (pure) Python library to read the Excel file (like openpyxl or any other) ?

Comment: The idea is to change the values and then read the output generated through an excel formula. Openpyxl doesnt allow that.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to create `win32com` variable after multi-threading.

Try this:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import json   
import pythoncom
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import Dispatch

xl = None

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/check", methods=['POST'])
def check():

    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
    xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.get_json()
        fname = data['fname']
        phName = data['PH_Name']
        liName = data['LI_NAME']
        ppm = data['PPM']
        policyTerm = data['Policy_Term']
        sumAssured = data['Sum_Assured']


        wb = None

        if xl : 
            wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(fname) 


            inp_sheet = wb.Sheets["Inputs"]

            #read data from sheet
            data = inp_sheet.Range('D8').Value


            wb.Close(False)
            xl.Quit()
            return (data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(threaded=True, port=5001, debug=True)
```